# A palavra "palrar"

Tags: vocabulário

De acordo com a tabuada [num artigo da Wikipédia sobre o Catalão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_language#Classification_and_relationship_with_other_Romance_languages) existe uma palavra «palrar», que é equivalente a «falar».

Mas eu não pude encontrar a palavra em nenhum dicionário.
É uma palavra real?

Comment: John, não te enganaste? Que dicionários consultaste? Eu quando busco "palrar" no Google obtenho uma quantidade de links a "palrar" em dicionários. Não conheço nenhum dicionário que não tenha a palavra. Não é é equivalente a "falar".

Comment: No artigo da Wikipedia, as fontes para o quadro onde se menciona palrar como uma das palavras equivalentes ao inglés "to speak", falar, são: "Jud, Jakob (1925). Problèmes de géographie linguistique romane (in French). Paris: Revue de Linguistique Romane. pp. 181–182." e "Colón, Germà (1993). El lèxic català dins la Romània. Biblioteca Lingüística Catalana. Valencia: Universitat de València. ISBN 84-370-1327-5.". Mas não tenho acesso à primeira e não consegui encontrar menções ao português na segunda.

Answer (score 2):

Melhor consultar dicionários melhores. :-)

**Todos** os que eu consultei contém o termo:

[Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/palrar):

> verbo intransitivo
>
> 1. Articular sons imperfeitos ou difíceis de perceber. = CHALREAR
> 2. Emitir a sua voz característica, que pode imitar sons da voz humana (ex.: o papagaio palra). = CHALREAR
> 3. Falar muito. = PALESTRAR, TAGARELAR

E também o [thefreedictionary](https://pt.thefreedictionary.com/palrar), o [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/palrar/), a [Infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/palrar) e o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/palrar).

Comment: Visto que você inicia com `Melhor consultar dicionários melhores. :-)` se 1) ou justificar porque os dicionários são melhores como fonte primária de referência do que a fonte fornecida pelo autor da pergunta, ou 2) reescrever sua pergunta para que não implique ter que justificar a afirmação forte? Em qualquer dos dois casos, eu daria +1. (e não não, não pretendo dar -1 nessa pergunta, mesmo sem qualquer alteração ou se não concordar comigo. Até porque sua resposta é boa. É que ela pode implicar ter que justificar mais conteúdo)

Comment: Oi @EmersonRochaLuiz, na minha busca, e também na do Jacinto (veja seu comentário na pergunta), na verdade essencialmente *qualquer* dicionário tem essa palavra. Ou seja, é no restante da resposta (e.g., a linha após a que você cita) que justifico porque John tem que procurar dicionários melhores: porque se teria que ter consultado dicionários muito ruins para não ter encontrado "palrar". Veja também que a fonte que John cita não se propõe a definir a palavra, então meu comentário não poderia se referir ao verbete da Wikipedia citado.

Answer (score 0):

A palavra "palrar" é atribuida aos sons emitidos pelos papagaios.
Normalmente, quando se diz que uma pessoa está a "palrar" significa que está a falar muito alto ou que está a dizer algo que não faz sentido.